# Router + change variable from child to parent component [Angularjs 2]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have `app.component` like this:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import {AuthTokenService} from './auth-token.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(
        private Auth: AuthTokenService) { };

    isGuest: any = this.Auth.canActivate();
    title = 'app works!';
}
```

And I need to change `isGuest` var from child component `login.component`

In `app.component.html` I have like this:

```
<h1>
    {{isGuest}}
</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I tried to change it with `@Output and Emitter` but it not working because I am using angular router.

Comment: `isGuest: any = this.Auth.canActivate();` this is incorrect line. apart from it , you can use service to make change(s) to parentcmp from childcmp.

Comment: Why is that incorrect? How it should be could you show me example?

Comment: `constructor(
        private Auth: AuthTokenService) {this.isGuest= Auth.canActivate();}` OR `ngOnInit(){
        this.isGuest= this.Auth.canActivate();}`

Comment: It return me error: `client:80[default] /home/dash/src/app/app.component.ts:13:13 
Property 'isGuest' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.`

Comment: `isGuest: any = this.Auth.canActivate();` is should work since it equals / a shorthand for `this.isGuest= Auth.canActivate();` inside the constructor (in this case you have to define it before - that´s why you´re getting the error). The service approach sounds correct!

Comment: Okay, could you help me with problem in my main post?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with updating the auth service to provide an Observable like in the Angular docs (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  /* ... */
  private canActivateSource  = new Subject<string>();
  public canActivate$ = this.canActivateSource.asObservable();
  /* ... */
  authenticate() {
    /* ... */
    if (authenticated) {
      this.canActivateSource.next(true);
    } else {
      this.canActivateSource.next(false);
    }
    /* ... */
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Then you can subscribe in your `app.component` like this:

```
this.Auth.canActivate$.subscribe(canActivate => {
  /* do something with canActivate */
});
```

And from your template, using the `async` pipe:

```
{{ Auth.canActivate$ | async }}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html